# in highchars can we give x axis and y axis plots together

Tags: highcharts

Can we give plot coordinates as a combination of string and integer without using x axis property categories?
For eg

series: [{
        name:'Before Campaign',
        data: [['Jan',20],['Feb',30]]
    }]

I have the example at http://jsfiddle.net/yxeLyao9/3/

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width: 400px; height: 400px"></div>
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            marginTop: 50,
            marginBottom: 50,
            marginLeft: 50,
            marginRight: 50,
            type: 'column'
        },
        title:{
            text:'Revenue'
        },
        /*xAxis: {
            //categories: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','','May','Jun','Jul','Aug']


        },*/


        series: [{
            name:'Before Campaign',
            data: [['Jan',20],['Feb',30]]
        }]

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want to explicitly specify the categories? You want the categories on the xaxis from the data?

Just specify that the xaxis is of type category and highcharts will take them from the data:

```
 xAxis: {
      type: 'category'
 }
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxeLyao9/4/).

Comment: thanks a lot. this was the answer i was looking for.